# how to get every index of a matching value in a list

Tags: java, list, indexof

I have a list (10000 elements) containing values 0 to 10. and I want to get all indices of list containing a specific value. 
(actually I need to get all indices of each of values).

what's the best way doing this?

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: I've tried iterating through the list, same as the answers.
Is it the only way? what if I want the position of all other values too?  actually I need them too! - editing the question!

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
   if(list.get(i) == 0){
      indexList.add(i);
   }
}
```

`indexList` contains all the indexes which value is `0`

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0, j=list.size(); i<list.size()&& j>0 && i<=j; i++,j--){
   if(list.get(i) == 0){
      indexList.add(i);
   }
   if(list.get(j) == 0){
      indexList.add(j);
   }
}
```

here in the code array is traced from both directions.
so in one loop 2 values are getting checked. this improves the performance from O(n) to O(n/2).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Code only answers are discouraged, especially because in this case, your answer doesn't make a whole lot of sense... why are you starting from both ends of the list (and won't list.get(j) be out of bounds the first time through the loop?).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to unwrap the loop so we can decrease time from O(n) to O(n/2). i added a additional condition to the loop i<=j so that loop runs n/2 times only.

Comment: You should also include an explanation about your code and why it answers the question. And you should do it quickly, your answer has been flagged as low quality

Comment: For the record, what you did does not really reduce the time.  Yes, the loop in theory is now of size n/2, but every time through the loop you do 5 comparisons and up to 2 adds, for a total of 5 * n / 2 comparisons and up to n adds, as opposed to the original 2 * n comparisons and up to n adds in the original.  (And you still are doing get out of bounds; you should initialize j to list.size()-1)